# "Invalid privatekey" when using JSch

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I'm using the following code to work with Git in a Java application. 
I have a valid key (use it all the time), and this specific code has work for me before with the same key and git repository, but now I get the following exception:

> invalid privatekey: [B@59c40796.

At this line:

```
jSch.addIdentity("<key_path>/private_key.pem");
```

My full code:

```
    String remoteURL = "ssh://git@<git_repository>";
    TransportConfigCallback transportConfigCallback = new SshTransportConfigCallback();
    File gitFolder = new File(workingDirectory);
    if (gitFolder.exists()) FileUtils.delete(gitFolder, FileUtils.RECURSIVE);

    Git git = Git.cloneRepository()
            .setURI(remoteURL)
            .setTransportConfigCallback(transportConfigCallback)
            .setDirectory(new File(workingDirectory))
            .call();
}


private static class SshTransportConfigCallback implements TransportConfigCallback {
    private final SshSessionFactory sshSessionFactory = new JschConfigSessionFactory() {
        @Override
        protected void configure(OpenSshConfig.Host hc, Session session) {
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        }

        @Override
        protected JSch createDefaultJSch(FS fs) throws JSchException {
            JSch jSch = super.createDefaultJSch(fs);
            jSch.addIdentity("<key_path>/private_key.pem");

            return jSch;
        }
    };
```

After searching online, I've change createDefaultJSch to use pemWriter:

```
@Override
protected JSch createDefaultJSch(FS fs) throws JSchException {
    JSch jSch = super.createDefaultJSch(fs);
    byte[] privateKeyPEM = null;

    try {
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("<my_key>.pem"), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privSpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(String.join("", lines)));
        RSAPrivateKey privKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(privSpec);

        PKCS8Generator pkcs8 = new PKCS8Generator(privKey);

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        PemWriter pemWriter = new PemWriter(writer);
        pemWriter.writeObject(pkcs8);

        privateKeyPEM = writer.toString().getBytes("US-ASCII");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    jSch.addIdentity("git", privateKeyPEM, null, null);

    return jSch;
}
```

But still getting *"invalid privatekey"* exception.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

I also stumbled upon this issue.
running **Jgit** on **mac**, for some users we saw the following exception:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1236)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:234)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: invalid privatekey: [B@e4487af
    at com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.load(KeyPair.java:664)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.load(KeyPair.java:561)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.IdentityFile.newInstance(IdentityFile.java:40)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.addIdentity(JSch.java:407)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.addIdentity(JSch.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getJSch(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.createSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.createSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:110)
```

The root cause was discovered to be the ssh private key mismatch.
The exception only happened for users with key of newer kind **ed25519**, which outputs this key header:

`-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----`

instead of kind **RSA**:

`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

regenerating an RSA key (`ssh-keygen -t rsa`), made the exception go away.

Edit following comments:
If you have OpenSSH 7.8 and above you might need to add -m PEM to the generation command:
`ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM`

Comment: Additionally, JSch seems to read `~/ssh/config` and fails if any non-RSA and/or non-PEM files are added to the list via `IdentityFile` directive.

Answer (score 248):

Recent versions of OpenSSH (7.8 and newer) generate keys in *new* OpenSSH format by default, which starts with:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

JSch does not support this key format.

---

You can use [`ssh-keygen`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen) to convert the key to the *classic* OpenSSH format:

```
ssh-keygen -p -f <privateKeyFile> -m pem -P passphrase -N passphrase
```

This "abuses" `-p` (change passphrase) command. It will overwrite the private key file identified by the `-f` option with a new private key in the *classic* OpenSSH format (`pem`). You can keep the current passphrase as the new passphrase. If the key was not encrypted with a passphrase, use `""` instead of `passphrase`. After, you can use `ssh-keygen -y -e -f <privateKeyFile> >temp.pub` to compare public keys and verify the existing public key works with the new format of private key.

For Windows users: Note that `ssh-keygen.exe` is now built-in in Windows 10/11. And can be [downloaded from Microsoft Win32-OpenSSH project](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH) for older versions of Windows.

---

On Windows, you can also use PuTTYgen (from [PuTTY package](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/)):

- Start PuTTYgen
- Load the key
- Go to *Conversions > Export OpenSSH key*.
  For RSA keys, it will use the *classic* format.

---

If you are creating a new key with `ssh-keygen`, just add [`-m PEM`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen#m) to generate the new key in the *classic* format:

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM
```

---

Actually, the original JSch does not seem to be actively maintained anymore. So particularly, if you are starting new project, it might not be the best library to begin with. JSch suffers from many compatibility problems nowadays. For some important ones, see:

- [Public key authentication fails with JSch but work with OpenSSH with the same key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72743823/850848)
- [Workaround for JSch unsupported KEX algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73862879/850848)

Instead, you might consider using this JSch fork:
https://github.com/mwiede/jsch

Among other, it does support the new OpenSSH key format.

Comment: extra kudos for pointing out how to convert an existing key instead of just generating a new one

Answer (score 20):

Instead of converting the `OPENSSH` key format to the format, which original JSch supports, you can also switch to a fork of JSch, which you can find at https://github.com/mwiede/jsch

Your only need to replace your JSch Maven coordinates with `com.github.mwiede:jsch:0.1.61`.

The fork does support the `OPENSSH` key format and several more algorithms, which might become important in the future, as OpenSSH servers will restrict the allowed sets of algorithms to the most secure ones.

Answer (score 8):

Quite late to reply, but want to leave track of how to face the issue.

The point, as many people already mentioned in their answers, is actually the way you generate the key and with the `-m PEM` option resolves.

However if as it just happened to me, you could not regenerate the key because the public part had already been installed in several servers, you can still convert your private key to a suitable format.

To do so, just issue the following command:

```
ssh-keygen -p -m pem -f id_rsa
```

It will ask for input of a new passphrase. With parameters `-P` (old passphrase) and `-N` (new passphrase) you can provide them at once, if needed.

Comment: True, but that's what my answer above says already.

Answer (score 4):

JSch does not support this key format. It supports only RSAPrivateKey. 
This command works for me. Try this solution

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 2048
```

//edited to rsa with 2048 keysize

Answer (score 1):

1. You read a file named `.pem` and de-base64 *all* of it and treat the result as PKCS8-unencrypted, apparently successfully. This means the file was NOT PEM-format. PEM format at minimum MUST have the dash-BEGIN and dash-END lines to be valid, which if not removed cause de-base64 to either fail or be wrong. (*Some* PEM formats also have 822-style headers which must be handled.)
2. You appear to be using BouncyCastle, but in my versions there is no `PKCS8Generator` constructor that takes only `RSAPrivateKey`. The closest thing that works is `JcaPKCS8Generator (RSAPrivateKey implements PrivateKey, OutputEncryptor=null)` (i.e. a different but related class, and two arguments not one).
3. `PemWriter` is buffered, and you didn't flush it before looking at the underlying `StringWriter`. As a result `writer.toString().getBytes()` is an empty/zero-length array, which `JSch` rightly considers invalid.

With #2 and #3 fixed and using my input, and calling `JSch` directly instead of via `JGit`, it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Besides issues with the format of the Private Key, this error "*JSchException: invalid privatekey*" can also occur when you:

- pass the Private Key as Byte Array, using this `addIdentity` overloaded method from JSch library: [`public void addIdentity(String name, byte[] prvkey, byte[] pubkey, byte[] passphrase)`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/JSch.html#addIdentity-java.lang.String-byte:A-byte:A-byte:A-)
- and run the application from a UNIX Operating System. For example, if you deploy your app to a Linux instance, in your chosen cloud provider.

The reason for this is an `if` statement from the JSch source code, class `KeyPair`, method `parseHeader` at line 803:
`if (buf[i] == 0x0d) {...}`: https://github.com/is/jsch/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jcraft/jsch/KeyPair.java#L803

Because of this `if` statement, are taken into consideration only the newline characters encoded like `\r` (0x0D == 13) (*applicable to Windows and MacOS*). But UNIX uses `\n` (0x0A == 10). Encodings are explained in this thread, for example: [What are the differences between char literals '\n' and '\r' in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260126/what-are-the-differences-between-char-literals-n-and-r-in-java)

---

So if your Private Key has the correct structure, but you run the app from Linux (*or any other UNIX OS*), then the Byte Array that corresponds to the content of your Private Key will be **different based on the Operating System from which you run your app**.

This is an example where the Byte Arrays have different contents:

- **When app runs on Linux**: [114, 115, 97, **10**, 69, 110] => **10** is the `"\n"`
- **When app runs on Windows**: [114, 115, 97, **13**, **10**, 69, 110] => **13 10** is the `"\r\n"`

[This image illustrates the different contents of the Byte Arrays converted back as Strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvvUl.png) , when the app is run as a WAR file from Linux and Windows, captured through remote debugging. I used the latest version of JSch that is currently available: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcraft/jsch/0.1.55

---

Therefore, **if you run your app from Linux**, then a solution would be to:

**1.** Get the InputStream from your Private and Public Keys (*the files should be added to the "resources" directory of your Spring project*):

```
InputStream privateKeyInputStream = new ClassPathResource("private-key.ppk").getInputStream();
InputStream publicKeyInputStream = new ClassPathResource("public-key.ppk").getInputStream();
```

**2.** Convert the InputStream to ByteArrays

```
byte[] privateKeyAsByteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(privateKeyInputStream);
byte[] publicKeyAsByteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(publicKeyInputStream);
```

**3.** Fix the encoding, by replacing the bytes of **10** (0x0A) with bytes of **13** (0x0D), before calling the `addIdentity` method from JSch:

```
for (int i = 0; i < privateKeyAsByteArray.length; i++) {
    if (privateKeyAsByteArray[i] == 10) {   // if current element is a 10 (\n) (UNIX)
        privateKeyAsByteArray[i] = 13;      // replace it with 13 (\r) (a byte that can be interpreted)
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < publicKeyAsByteArray.length; i++) {
    if (publicKeyAsByteArray[i] == 10) {    // if current element is a 10 (\n) (UNIX)
        publicKeyAsByteArray[i] = 13;       // replace it with 13 (\r) (a byte that can be interpreted)
    }
}
```

**4.** Call the `addIdentity` method:

```java
jSch.addIdentity("private-key.ppk", privateKeyAsByteArray, publicKeyAsByteArray, passphraseAsString.getBytes());
```

---

I was thinking that this scenario could help someone who faces this error, until that `if` statement from the source code of the JSch library is updated to support also UNIX characters.

Comment: The original JSch library seems to be abandoned. But this GihHub project continues to add improvements and updates to the original implementation. From version 0.2.7 upwards, this problem with the `invalid private-key for UNIX runs` was solved: https://github.com/mwiede/jsch

Answer (score 1):

Since [JSCH](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) is no longer maintained and doesn't support most of the latest OpenSSH key algorithms, JGIT has now turned into [Apache MINA SSHD](https://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/) for SSH connectivity. For this JGIT also provides the artifact [org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.apache](https://git.eclipse.org/r/plugins/gitiles/jgit/jgit/+/master/org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.apache/) .
To use this all you have to do is switch the dependency from JGit jsch artifact to JGit ssh.apache artifact and set a new SshdSessionFactory instance (which is apache implementation of SshSessionFactory) to org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.

Switch dependency;

From :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.jsch</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

To :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.apache</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Setting SshdSessionFactory for a private key with passphrase;

```
TransportCommand<T, C> transportCommand = <Any Transport command in JGIT>;
File sshDir = new File(FS.DETECTED.userHome(), File.separator+SSH_DIR);
      SshdSessionFactory sshSessionFactory = new SshdSessionFactoryBuilder().setPreferredAuthentications("publickey")
        .setHomeDirectory(FS.DETECTED.userHome()).setSshDirectory(sshDir)
        .setKeyPasswordProvider(cp -> new IdentityPasswordProvider(cp)
        {
          @Override
          protected char[] getPassword(URIish uri, String message)
          {
            return passphrase.toCharArray();
          }
        }).build(null);
 transportCommand.setTransportConfigCallback(transport -> ((SshTransport) transport).setSshSessionFactory(sshSessionFactory));
```

Answer (score 0):

So have the same problem fix it by **PuTTYgen**

[image]

1)Open PuTTYgen

2. Press "Load" and choose the privateKey

[image]

3)press now on "Conversions" -> and choose the first option "Export OPENSSH key"

[image]

4. save it as file (not need any format) and use it

Answer (score 0):

From my sides, I meet the same issue. In my host file, there has this configuration below, which makes jsch reading ssh config by id_ed25519. You should use id_rsa.

```
   Host *
     AddKeysToAgent yes
     IdentityFile /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this dependency in your maven pom.xml and ensure that you check from which JSH class dependency is getting used in your code . Sometimes older dependency gets picked . Here using below dependency even OPEN SSH KEY will work fine

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mwiede</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score -2):

I wanted to add that in order to avoid the below headers you need to create the key with

```
-C "any-comment"
```

Headers that will be removed from the private Key:

```
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,3551DFC375229D5758289E8D366082FE
```

Leaving only

```
 -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
YOUR_KEY_HERE
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: That's not correct. Those headers indicate that the key is encrypted with a passphrase. They have nothing to do with `-C`.

Comment: for some reason in my configuration the same command with the `-C` returned the file without the headers. The RSA key did not work if I removed them manually, I had to use the `-C`

Comment: You have probably entered a passphrase when prompted in one case, while not in the other.