# Create a SSH private key with ssh-keygen that is accepted by JSch

Tags: macos, ssh, jsch, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

Not directly a programming question, but somehow related. JSch (Java SSH library) does not seem to allow private keys that macOS 10.14 creates using

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
```

What command I should use to create a private key file with such a format:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,....
```

which is accepted by JSch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to need a key in classic OpenSSH format. Recent versions of OpenSSH generate keys in a new format.

To force the classic format, use [`-m PEM` switch](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen#m).

See also ["Invalid privatekey" when using JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53134212/850848).