# How to add an ed25519 ssh key to eclipse for use with github?

Tags: git, eclipse, github, ssh-keys

I used Git for Windows (v2.30.1) to create an ed25519 ssh key with
`ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C “<github email>”` per [this github doc](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) and [added it to my account](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account). I verified it works from Git CMD with `ssh -T git@github.com`.

To load it into eclipse (v2020-12; EGit v5.11), I went here: `Preferences --> SSH2 --> Key Management --> Load Existing Key...`

When attempting to add the private key, I got this error `failed to load given file`. [EGit v5.4+ "supports" an ed25519 key](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/5.4), but I could find no instructions ([expected them here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#SSH_config)) for how to get one into eclipse. Googling for the error was unhelpful.

How do I use my ed25519 key with eclipse?

Comment: Did you add the private key in the preferences in _General > Network Connections > SSH2_ in the tab _General_ (as described in the [EGit help/documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Eclipse_SSH_Configuration))?

Comment: @howlger Your comment got me one step closer. I was already on the Key Management tab (having generated a RSA key) and tried to Load Existing Key from there. From the General tab, I successfully added my ed25519 key. Now getting a connection error that I'm investigating...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems odd that you can't use `Load Existing Key` to, well, load an ssh key. I’m not the only one to make that mistake... Thanks to Howlger for pointing out [the relevant doc here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Eclipse_SSH_Configuration). The correct way to add a key is from the General tab by clicking `Add Private Key…` and selecting your ed25519 private key file (not the one ending in “.pub”).

I am fairly new at git, so I'm doing as much of it in the eclipse GUI (aka EGit) as possible. I had already cloned a public repo from the Git perspective like so:

1. Clicked `Clone a Git Repository and add the clone to this view` --> `GitHub`
2. Typed org.aspectj in Search box and clicked `Search`
3. Selected eclipse/org.aspectj and clicked Next
4. Selected the master branch --> Next --> entered local directory
5. Clicked Finish

The steps are important because EGit defaulted the repo URI for the remote `origin` like this: `https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj`. Now that I had my ssh key loaded, I wanted to change that. So, still in the Git perspective, under `Remotes` I right-clicked `origin`, clicked `Configure push`, then `Change…` and clicked the protocol dropdown, selected `ssh` and `Finish`. Back at the `Configure push for remote ‘origin’` window, I clicked `Save and Push` and got this error:

```
Can't connect to any repository: ssh://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj (ssh://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj: Cannot log in at github.com:22)
```

Troubleshooting finally led me to [this github documentation about the “git” user](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@2.21/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey#always-use-the-git-user) . I only needed to update origin’s URI to `ssh://git@github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj` and then it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

For testing, try the same key, but without a passphrase.

The error "`failed to load given file`" [was indeed reported](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/200827/) for keys (even simple `id_rsa` ones) with passphrase.

[Eclipse issue 326526](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=326526) mentions:

> Another, much simpler workaround is to remove the (AES) passphrase using OpenSSH and then ask the (old) JSch to set the same passphrase again - using DES3 ([DES seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53558436/6309)).
>
> Even though OpenSSH's is now using AES by default it supports DES3 fine. Using DES3 the same passphrase can be shared across all agents. No GIT_SSH variable required. Tested.

That means:

Recreate your key *with* passphrase if you want, but using the old PEM format:

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM ...
```

That or you would need to [use a fork of Jsch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65933464/6309).

Comment: Unfortunately, this bug doesn't apply to EGit 5.11 -- use of Jsch has been dropped in favor of  Apache MINA sshd.

Comment: @cb4 OK: maybe this is linked to MINA then.