# Ant scp task: JSchException: invalid privatekey

Tags: ssh, ant, sftp, scp, jsch

I created a new key pair using ssh-keygen and added the public key on the server. Using `sftp -i private_key_file user@server` I can successfully open a connection to the server and put files.
However, when I try to use the Ant scp task I receive:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: invalid privatekey: [B@5e9d5728
```

The relevant part of the Ant script:

```
<scp file="local-file.zip"
             trust="true"
             sftp="true"
             todir="user@server:/dir/to/put/files"
             keyfile="private_key_file"
             verbose="true"/>
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: What does your key file look like? Show us its structure. + What version of JSch are you using?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Your questions point into the right direction ... see my answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like in recent OpenSSH versions (I have 7.9 installed in my F29) ssh-keygen generates a slightly different key format
which starts now with:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

instead of:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I have version 1.50 of JSch installed, which does not like the new format.
Using `-m PEM` option during key generation solved my issue:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM
```

Found the solution in this thread: [Invalid privateKey when using JGit and JSCH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53134212/invalid-privatekey-when-using-jgit-and-jsch).
Thanks and credits go to [Natan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1980490/natan) and [Roman Vottner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1377895/roman-vottner) !

(Not sure if there also is a new version of JSch available that will accept the new key format.)

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers. + And you should upgrade your copy of JSch in any case.