# Auth fail when running `sbt new`

Tags: sbt, giter8

Here's a transcript so far:

```
$ sbt new lagom/lagom-scala.g8
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/abrahma/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Set current project to lagomlife (in build file:/Users/abrahma/Bitbucket/Practice-Scala/LagomLife/)
[info] Set current project to lagomlife (in build file:/Users/abrahma/Bitbucket/Practice-Scala/LagomLife/)

ssh://git@github.com/lagom/lagom-scala.g8.git: Auth fail
```

I've verified authentication with 
GitHub:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi agam! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Also verified that I can access the repo in question (i.e. I can do the following, in a separate location):

```
git clone ssh://git@github.com/lagom/lagom-scala.g8.git
```

*Edit:* fwiw I'm able to work around whatever the root cause is here:

```
git clone ssh://git@github.com/lagom/lagom-scala.g8.git
g8 file:///Users/abrahma/tmp/lagom-scala.g8
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this problem as well, and solved it by removing the following from my *~/.gitconfig*:

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
  insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

Comment: This worked for me, just annoying because I had to add that to my `.gitconfig` file to get other Go processes to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using OpenSSH 7.8 or newer, and have you recently created your private key?

If so you might be running into the issue described in [“Invalid privatekey” when using JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53783283/3827) aka [jsch#129](https://sourceforge.net/p/jsch/bugs/129/).

> The root cause was discovered to be the ssh private key mismatch.

The question has a workaround to convert the key file to an older format if that's the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your SSH key to the agent:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```