# Basic new dotty project instructions fail with "invalid privatekey", how to fix?

Tags: scala, sbt, dotty, scala-3

The [getting started page](https://dotty.epfl.ch/#getting-started) for Dotty gives this instruction for starting a new project:

> Create a Dotty project:

```
sbt new lampepfl/dotty.g8
```

When I run this, I get this error:

```
git@github.com:lampepfl/dotty.g8.git: invalid privatekey: [B@58aa5c94
```

It appears that possibly my authentication with GitHub is failing. Some googling led me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53134212/invalid-privatekey-when-using-jsch/53783283#53783283) which says it is due to using a newer OpenSSH `id_rsa` key.

So I created a new SSH key `~/.ssh/id_rsa.nonopenssh`, added it to my SSH agent, and added it to my GitHub account, but I'm still getting the error. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that merely adding the non-OpenSSH key is not good enough. For me I could only get it working once I'd removed the OpenSSH key from GitHub entirely. I also named the non-OpenSSH key `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, which may not be necessary but it's what I did.

Summary:

1. (Might be optional) Rename your OpenSSH `id_rsa` keys: `cd ~/.ssh && mv id_rsa id_rsa.bak && mv id_rsa.pub id_rsa.pub.bak`
2. [Generate a new *RSA* key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53783283/446554): `ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM`
3. `ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
4. Delete the old key from GitHub
5. Add the key to GitHub