# Workaround for JSch unsupported KEX algorithms

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

We are using JSch library (jsch-0.1.55.jar) to make connection with SFTP server (Bitvise).
I am using the algorithm `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1`  and it's working fine. But when I use the following algorithms it shows the error

> Algorithm negotiation fail

- `curve25519-sha256@libssh.org`
- `diffie-hellman-group18-sha512`
- `diffie-hellman-group16-sha512`
- `diffie-hellman-group14-sha256`

Are the above algorithms supported by JSch?

If they are not, Can someone please help with the article or any workaround to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 4):

JSch 0.1.55 does not support any of those.

But [@mwiede's fork of JSch](https://github.com/mwiede/jsch) supports all of them.

Comment: I've recently switched to this one as well. `camel-sftp` and Red Hat use it, so that gives some more confidence about using "just any" library.